# array formula to auto increment if conditions

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Need array formula to auto increment column A when date is set and amount is not equal to 0

[sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uUcrFazzehAnrZ4E2-ALSQGj_owSi-74mvNKFQRisPU/edit#gid=0)

[image]

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful. I know you provided a sheet link (thanks!), but see [ask] and point that says the question post should be sufficient without links to external repros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do that:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B*(C2:C&""<>"0");SCAN(;ROW(B2:C)-1;LAMBDA(a;c;a+IF(INDEX(B2:B;c)*INDEX(C2:C&""<>"0";c);1)));))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `scan()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    len(B2:B) * (to_text(C2:C) <> "0"); 
    scan( 
      ""; isdate_strict(B2:B) * (to_text(C2:C) <> "0"); 
      lambda( 
        result; increment; 
        result + increment
      )
    ); 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

another approach:

```
=LAMBDA(y,MAP(INDEX(y,,1),INDEX(y,,2),LAMBDA(r,c,IF(r=0,,c))))(LAMBDA(z,{z,SCAN(,z,LAMBDA(ac,cv,ac+cv))})(INDEX(ISDATE_STRICT(B2:B)*(C2:C&""<>"0"))))
```

- 

[image]